# laws of probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that there is a $60\%$ probability that the product will be a success on the market (that means, the probability of failure is $40\%$). If the product is a success, you will get a profit of $\$200,000$, and if it is a failure, you will incur a loss of $\$100,000$. Should you develop this product? How do you make a decision in this situation? Also, how can one come up with the probability of success (or failure)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no right or wrong answer to whether or not you should develop the product.  We can at least come up with the expected profit (with the convention that a loss is negative profit).  This is just:

$$\mathbb{E}(P)=\$200,000\times60\%+(-\$100,000\times40\%)=\$80,000$$

Since this is positive it might be decided to develop the product.

To come up with success and failure probabilities you would really need to define what you mean by "success" and "failure".  It could be defined in terms of total number of units sold or perhaps total generated revenue or perhaps something else quantifiable and essential to the company's bottom line.  Failure would then be defined as the complementary event or the even where say a minimum number of units is **NOT** sold or if you **fall short** of a certain revenue threshold.  Again, the risk factors impacting "success" here are fairly open ended and depend on the uniqueness of the product.

Answer (score 0):

$$.6(200,000) - .4(100,000) = 80,000$$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Answer (score 0):

You know that $60\%$ of the time, your product will succeed, and you'll gain $\$200,000;$ but $40\%$ of the time, your product will fail, and you'll lose $\$100,000$. Put another way, on average, for every $100$ you make, you will gain $\$12$ million, but lose $\$4$ million, for a net profit of $\$8$ million for every hundred that you make, meaning you should expect a profit of $\$80,000$ for every one that you make. Since you can expect a profit (rather substantial, too), then you should develop the product.

As for how to determine the probabilities of success or failure, I'm afraid there isn't enough context for me to even speculate.

Comment: You are very welcome. Just so you know, after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). You can only accept one answer per question, though. Most folks pick the most helpful one, with ties going to the one posted first.

Comment: After you've been around long enough to gain [sufficient reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) ($15,$ in this case), you can "upvote" (with the up arrow) any number of questions and answers that you find useful (up to $40$ per day) with the little up arrow on the post. This helps ensure that better answers (and answerers) get more attention, and make the site better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are CEO of a firm that puts out hundreds of new products each year then your product manager might have reason to venture the claim that a particular product proposed to him has  "a $60\%$ chance of success". In this case introducing the product will lead to an expected profit of $0.6\cdot 200\,00-0.4\cdot100\,000=80\,000$ dollars, whereas doing nothing results in a zero sum.

But if this particular product is the one and only product that you  ever would be thinking of putting into the market then there is no such thing as a probability that it will be a success.